# how i install a postgis in Managed postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, postgresql-extensions, postgis-raster

i have a managed postgresql in oci , i want to install extension(postgis)

i just access to the primary by psql cli

```
 `postgres-> \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)`
```

that a list of all extension ..

i try this command :

```
 postgres=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
```

and give me that error :

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/lib/postgresql/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

is there another way ?

thank you

Comment: The question is not about development but what your database manager does or does not provide. You need to contact your provider. Voting to close

Comment: @Belayer The answer *is* about what OCI does or does not provide. The question is about setting up PostGIS. I agree it's definitely most suitable for Oracle support forums, or at least DBA StackExchange, not necessarily SO, but I don't think findings from an answer should cascade back to the judgement of the question validity. There are currently [1261 threads that discuss "installing postgis"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=installing+postgis) here on SO, so I don't think it's such a bad thing to ask about or a bad place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, PostGIS isn't on the list of [extensions supported by OCI](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/postgresql/extensions.htm). AWS RDS [has it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html), Azure [has it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/concepts-extensions), [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgresql-extensions-supported-by-cloud-sql) does have it, Oracle doesn't.